# Making Clozure Common Lisp recognize my custom HOME on Windows

Tags: windows, common-lisp, home-directory, ccl

I'm writing Common Lisp on WinXP in Emacs (downloaded a fork of Lispbox that comes with CCL 1.11 and changed the default `.emacs.d` to Spacemacs)

I have a .bat file that launches emacs and sets HOME to my custom home directory (I want this setup to be portable)

My files are organized in the following fashion:

```
lispbox
|-home
 |-src
  |-projects and stuff
 |-.emacs.d
|-mingw
|-emacs
|-ccl
|-git
|-aspell
|-quicklisp
|-lispbox.bat (this sets HOME to the home folder and does some PATH magic before launching emacs)
```

It works in elisp (`(file-truename "~")` returns `d:/Program Files/Lispbox/lispbox/home`), and CL's `(getenv "HOME")` returns my custom directory
But when I try to reference `~` in stuff like quickproject or pathname it returns the default `C:\Documents and Settings\USER` (quickproject created my project at `C:\Documents and Settings\USER\src\myproj`)

Is there a way to make CCL use my home directory whenever I refer to `~` (preferably without affecting files outside my lisp directory, I don't want to symlink my home to the system home or something)?

Comment: CCL on Windows appears to determine a user's home directory from the `USERPROFILE` environment variable: [get-user-home-dir](https://github.com/Clozure/ccl/blob/master/level-1/linux-files.lisp#L939) and [tilde-expand](https://github.com/Clozure/ccl/blob/master/level-1/linux-files.lisp#L666).

Comment: It worked! thanks :)